# How can I express this in Big O notation?

Tags: math, big-o

How can I express `2(3(logn-1))` in Big O notation?
Is it `2n` or `2log n`?

Answer (score 2):

This is one case where the basis of the logarithm matters. So lets say, the basis of your logarithm is `a`. You can change it to base 3 by

```
logan = log₃n / log₃a
```

Now you can simplify the exponent

```
3logan - 1 = 3log₃n / log₃a - 1 = n1/log₃a / 3
```

So in total you get

```
2n1/log₃a / 3 = 2n1/log₃a / 3 ⋅ 21/3 ∈ O(2n1/log₃a)
```

If `a = 3` the complexity would be `O(2ⁿ)`. If `a = 2`, the complexity would be `O(2nc)`, with
`c = 1/log₃2 ≈ 1.5850`.

Notice: `2nc = 2(nc) ≠ (2n)c = 2cn`. So you cannot simplify the complexity more.

Comment: Thumbs up for "this is once case where the basis of the logarithm matters"